# Makefile pattern match on multiple directories

Tags: makefile, pattern-matching

I have a make target for *.abc files that need then trigger DIR/%.xyz. The problem is DIR is passed in as a list of directories. %.xyz is unique and exists only in one place. I've tried using a foreach without any luck. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
OtherDir:=dir1 dir2 dir3
${SOURCE_DIR}/%.abc: $(foreach dir, OtherDir, $(if ${dir}/%.xyz,,$(info Match found in ${dir}))
```

Edit - Found one possible solution. Instead of storing path to ${dir}/$*.xyz it is passed directly into the compile step.
OtherDir:=dir1 dir2 dir3

```
${SOURCE_DIR}/%.abc:
    $(call status, Do the stuff)
    3rd_party_compile_tool $(foreach dir, ${OtherDir}, $(wildcard ${dir}/$*.xyz))
```

Comment: Sorry but what you did does not make any sense to me. What are you trying to do? What command would you like to type (`make something`) and what result would you like to see?

Comment: For example if input is src/foo.abc, I want the output to dir2/foo.xyz. Assuming foo.xyz exists in dir2.

Comment: So, if you type `make src/foo.abc` and `dir2/foo.xyz` exists, you want the string `dir2/foo.xyz` to be printed on your standard output?

Comment: Store it in a variable

Comment: Store `dir2/foo.xyz` in variable and then what? Exit? In what you show you don't try to assign any variable (except `OtherDir` for which you apparently do not need help). Sorry, I give up, I have no clue about what you try to achieve. Try maybe to rework your question and better explain what you want, maybe others will understand and find a way to help.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I updated the OP with one possible solution. Not sure if there is a better way?

Comment: your "possible solution" will always rebuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `foreach` that you wanted to do needs [secondary expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion), so that it is evaluated when the stem (the `%` part) is set. Consider the following `Makefile`:

```
SOURCE_DIR := src
OtherDir := dir1 dir2 dir3

.SECONDEXPANSION:

$(SOURCE_DIR)/%.abc: $$(foreach dir,$(OtherDir),$$(wildcard $$(dir)/$$*.xyz))
        echo Making $@ from $^
```

with given file structure:

```
.
./dir1
./dir2
./dir2/foo.xyz
./dir3
./dir3/bar.xyz
./Makefile
```

it will match the appropriate prerequisite based on the stem:

```
$ make -s src/foo.abc src/bar.abc
Making src/foo.abc from dir2/foo.xyz
Making src/bar.abc from dir3/bar.xyz
```

Comment: Learned something new. I thought there must be a way to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So, for starters, the way you're trying to do things makes it sound like there's a flaw in your overall make design  (specifically, if you have two %.xyz's with the same name in multiple directories, this will cause you issues -- and while you might not have any now, this is a sharp stick).

If you did want to do this, you could use a template/eval to generate a separate pattern rule for each of the dirs.   Make will pick the first pattern that matches when trying to build `%.abc`.

```
OtherDir:=dir1 dir2 dir3

define abc_rule
${SOURCE_DIR}/%.abc: $(1)/%.xyz
    @3rd_party_compile_tool $^
endef

$(foreach dir,${OtherDir},$(eval $(call abc_rule,${dir})))
```

(notice that your updated posted solution will have issues due to dependencies).